# JSONSerialization issue with double quotes

Tags: json, swift

I am facing a problem related to JSONSerialization in iOS Swift.

When my data is:

```
{
  "key": "value"
}
```

```
var str = "{\"key\":\"value\"}"
var json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: str.data(using: .utf8)!, options: [])
```

Everything is working fine.

But I am having problem with parsing data where value is with ` " ``
means value is with double quotes either at start or end.

When my data is:

```
{
  "key": ""value""
}
```

```
var str = "{\"key\":\"\"value\"\"}"
```

Comment: That isn't valid JSON. Are you the one in charge of building the `str` you show in the last snippet? Or, is there invalid JSON coming from a server that's out of your control?

Comment: No, I am not in charge of building str, I am getting this string from the server. This is a rare incident where values have quotes in start or end.

Comment: As @jnpdx mentioned, this is invalid JSON. The [spec](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) also tells you that this is invalid JSON. The double quote is a meaningful character if not escaped and will be interpreted by the JSON parser

Comment: Yeah; before you parse this, you'll need to massage it into legal JSON. The better way to do that is to fix the server. Fixing invalid data is rarely robust. But if you're committed to doing that, you'll need to do String manipulation, probably with Regex to look for `""([^"]*)""` and replace it with `"\"$1\""`. But that's not going to work if the `"` is anywhere but the start and end of the value. If it could be embedded, then you'd almost certainly have to write a custom parser to handle that. I highly recommend fixing the server.